# Embed form within a form

Tags: 7, forms

I am building on an existing site, adding / modifying functionality to it.

There is a form, which is a part of a (sort of a) multi-step form which I need to alter, and add another form to it.

So, I added the following to the existing form:

```
// Some form elements above this.
$form['new_form_element']['search'] = drupal_get_form('MY_PROJECT_search_form');
// Some form elements after this
```

And the `MY_PROJECT_search_form` function returns the form, which is then embedded in the original form. The form is rendered properly.

However, when I submit the form, I get the following notice :

> The form has become outdated. Copy any unsaved work in the form below and then reload this page.

I believe that is because the two forms are getting submitted at the same time, and the submission of one of them is failing.
I have tried adding `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE` to the submit functions, but it did not work.
I have also tried adding an `markup` type field and embedding form in as
`'#markup' = render(drupal_get_form('MY_PROJECT_search_form'));`
But, I am not able to implement AJAX in the embedded form after that.

Is there any other *better* way to embed a form?

**Note:** There is no other option then to embed a separate form to the current form.

Comment: what about adding the elements of the embedded form to the original form, and adjust/split in the submit handler? Not terribly pretty, but could be a temporary solution

Comment: @Geoff I was afraid that would be last option, until I come up with a better solution. But, as you said it could be used as a temporary solution.

Comment: take a look at this [question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50531/two-forms-on-the-same-page-both-submit-the-same) - it could be doing something similar

Answer (score 1):

Nesting forms in other forms is not valid in html.
see this post 
[html nesting forms in forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555928/is-it-valid-to-have-a-html-form-inside-another-html-form)

You can always try calling the form directly via the actual form function instead of via drupal_get_form since the function returns a valid array of form elements. 
you'll have to somehow compensate for the missing `hook_form_alter` and `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter`.

Note I haven't actually tried this, so I'm not sure how it will react on the empty $form/$form_state params.

That already gets you all the fields in a dynamic way. 
Perhaps you can build a similar work around calling the submit/validate handlers directly too.